# document.selection unpredictable behavior

Tags: flash, jsfl

I'm using Flash CS6, and I am trying to develop a more involved script, but I'm stuck on the following problem. The following code does not behave as expected:

```
var dom = fl.getDocumentDOM();
dom.selectNone();
fl.trace(dom.selected.symbolType);
```

I would expect an error, telling me that the selection has no properties - because I've deselected all, dom.selected should be empty. Instead, I get this trace output:

```
graphic
```

My document has a library with graphics, bitmaps, and movie clips. When I first ran this script, I had a graphic selected on the stage. In the UI, I tried:

- Deselecting all
- Selecting a group of elements of different types and on different layers
- Selecting a single movie clip
- Deleting everything in the scene, including all library items, frames, and layers

**No matter what I do**, I get the output telling me that I have a graphic selected.

Upon further investigation, I reloaded the file. This time I ran the script with nothing selected. I got the error I expected! So I edited the script to get rid of the deselection, so I could see info about my current selection:

```
var dom = fl.getDocumentDOM();
//dom.selectNone();
fl.trace(dom.selected.symbolType);
```

However, then I selected some of the objects and continued to get the "dom.selection is empty" error as if I still had nothing selected. So I quit Flash and opened the file again.

Now **no matter what I have selected**, I get the error that says the selection is empty. So, I am either missing something essential or this is not at all the way this object is supposed to work. How do I access/set the current selection as I am expecting?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried:

```
var selection = fl.getDocumentDOM().selection[0];
```